# How to keep ssh connection open until the last stage of reboot or shutdown?

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh

When rebooting or shutting down a headless server, the ssh connection disconnects immediately.

Sometimes the server takes hours to reboot or shutdown. Since it's headless, all I can do is wait.

Can I keep the ssh connection open as long as possible so that I can know what is happening?

Comment: No and why would you need that? The reason is going to be shown in a log file (probably  in /var/log/ or journalctl).

Comment: I can read the log, but I have to wait before I can do that. And I don't know how long I will wait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the systemd unit definition at `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service` (find the name for your distro easily among output lines of `systemctl status ssh`), it would likely state `WantedBy=multi-user.target` at the end (`Install` section).

This means that when this "target" ceases to be, all services wanted just by it should disappear (stop). Targets generally serve as umbrellas to start services as needed at some point in runtime lifecycle, and stop them when no longer needed. Shutdown/Reboot activity disables `multi-user.target` and enables `shutdown.target` (some distros also define `reboot.target`, `poweroff.target`, etc.)

You can add a drop-in service configuration (so it is locally maintained and does not conflict with packaging updates) like this:

```
:; mkdir /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d

:; cat > /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d/shutdown.conf <<EOF
[Unit]
# Clear the list (remove default shutdown.target from it)
#Conflicts=
DefaultDependencies=no

[Install]
WantedBy=shutdown.target
# emergency.target rescue.target
EOF

# Update systemd runtime knowledge
:; systemctl daemon-reload

# Resync symlinks which are what matters for boots
:; systemctl enable ssh
```

For good measure you might want to add `emergency.target rescue.target` to the list, although keep in mind that this might get `sshd` to run when e.g. non-root home directories are not available.

Verify with:

```
:; systemctl show -p WantedBy,Conflicts ssh
:; systemd-delta --type=extended
```

This should allow your ssh connection to stay up as long as `networking.service` and so IP addressing is available (disappears when all who depend on it get stopped, usually very late in the lifecycle).